# docker-compose - Can't connect to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

TL;DR: WordPress cannot connect to MySQL using the below docker-compose config. **Error establishing a database connection.**  Why?

I am using the following `docker-compose.yml` file to set up a LEMP dev environment.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/config/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ../wordpress:/var/www/wordpress
      - ./nginx/log:/var/log/nginx
    depends_on:
      - php
  php:
    image: php:fpm
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - ../wordpress:/var/www/wordpress
    depends_on:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ado
      MYSQL_USER: ado
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

(I also manually do the following to install `php-mysql`)

```
// inside php (`docker-compose exec php sh`)
docker-php-ext-install mysqli

// back on my local machine
docker restart <php's container id>
```

Note: I tried using both `localhost` & `mysql` for MySQL's host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Got it.

I had added the MySQL environment variables after manually creating a database inside the `mysql` service.

```
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
  MYSQL_DATABASE: ado
  MYSQL_USER: ado
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
```

I'm not 100% sure why, but after deleting MySQL's data in `./mysql/data`, doing `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up -d` again (and install php-mysqli with `docker-php-ext-install mysqli` inside the PHP service), everything worked.

Then, the WordPress install screen came up.  And after installing....... I got a blank white screen!

Well, that's because my WordPress files did not include the default themes.

After going to `/wp-admin` and activating a theme, everything finally... worked.

For completeness, here is my nginx config located in `./nginx/config/default.conf`:

```
server {
  listen               80 default_server;
  listen               [::]:80 default_server;

  root                 /var/www/wordpress;
  index                index.php index.html;

  location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
  }

  location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
  }

  location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```